# superscript in Java String

Tags: java

Does Java String supports superscript in a String? If yes then how can I use it, I have searched the web and also the API but not able to figure out how I can use it for my purpose

Although this will be printed on the webpage, I cannot use the html tag here, any suggestions please

Comment: A Java String is just a collection of characters, i.e. plain text...

Comment: ... Well. If you want superscripts in a browser, you're going to have to use CSS or HTML. A string is just that-a string, it doesn't have any intrinsic formatting.

Comment: I don't know why everyone is talking about graphics components and fonts. OP, please clarify your question: where and how will this string be displayed?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check out java.text.AttributedString, which supports subscripts and more.  e.g., in your paintComponent() you could go:

```
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      AttributedString as = new AttributedString("I love you 104 gazillion");
      as.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT, TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT_SUPER, 13, 14);
      as.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FOREGROUND, Color.RED, 2, 6);
      g.drawString(as.getIterator(), 20, 20);
   }
```

[image: Should look like this]

Comment: what about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12208275/output-a-number-raised-to-a-power-as-a-string ?

Answer (score 18):

Just in case somebody uses these handmade functions:

```
public static String superscript(String str) {
    str = str.replaceAll("0", "⁰");
    str = str.replaceAll("1", "¹");
    str = str.replaceAll("2", "²");
    str = str.replaceAll("3", "³");
    str = str.replaceAll("4", "⁴");
    str = str.replaceAll("5", "⁵");
    str = str.replaceAll("6", "⁶");
    str = str.replaceAll("7", "⁷");
    str = str.replaceAll("8", "⁸");
    str = str.replaceAll("9", "⁹");         
    return str;
}

public static String subscript(String str) {
    str = str.replaceAll("0", "₀");
    str = str.replaceAll("1", "₁");
    str = str.replaceAll("2", "₂");
    str = str.replaceAll("3", "₃");
    str = str.replaceAll("4", "₄");
    str = str.replaceAll("5", "₅");
    str = str.replaceAll("6", "₆");
    str = str.replaceAll("7", "₇");
    str = str.replaceAll("8", "₈");
    str = str.replaceAll("9", "₉");
    return str;
}
```

Note, that there is a little ambiguity about ¹²³, because they are acsii symbols 251, 253 and 252 and they are also utf-symbols. I prefer to use acsii because they more probably are supported by font, but here you should decide what you actually want to use.

Comment: There's no such thing as a UTF symbol, and codepoints 251-253 in unicode are 'ûüý'.  Also, your subscript '5' is actually a superscript.

Comment: 1. symbol supported in UTF-8 is an utf-symbol
2. thanks, corrected

Comment: UTF-8 and UTF-16 and UTF-32 are not symbol sets.  They are mappings from byte strings to strings of integers of varying sizes.  Unicode and ASCII are mappings from integers to symbols so there are ASCII symbols and unicode symbols, but not UTF-* symbols, only UTF-?? encodings of unicode/ASCII symbols.  As you can see, the only numeric symbols in [extended ASCII](http://www.ascii-code.com/) are regular digits and fractions.  No superscripts or subscripts.

Comment: @Mike Samuel 1. thank you for explaination about utf mappings and symbol mappings.
2. But you are actually not correca about ¹²³ in extended ASCII(Latin-1). You can find them following your link. DEC codes 178=², 179=³ and 185=¹. Now i am not sure about ambiguity and wondering what do the symbols 0x2071, 0x2072 and 0x2073 are supposed to mean in unicode table http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html. The symbols ⁴-⁹ have codes 0x2074-0x2079, ⁰=0x2070, but 0x2071-3 are shown as ⁱ⁲⁳ in my browser. May  be they are a latin superscripted symbols, i am not sure.

Comment: I see the 178,179,185 entries in the table now.  Apologies, I must have missed them in my earlier scan.  http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2070.pdf says "2071 i SUPERSCRIPT SMALL LATIN I - functions as a modifier letter", and "2072 reserved" and "2073 reserved" so it looks like there are no superscript 1,2,or 3 in that code page.

Comment: I tried this on Android TextView but it works for superscript 1 to 4 only. It does not work with 0, 5 to 9 while printing on the TextView!!!

Comment: Have an upvote, but this answer is a bit limited in terms of answering the question entirely. Nice one though :P

Answer (score 5):

No, a string is just a sequence of UTF-16 code-units.  There are unicode codepoints for [individual super-script characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts) in the math code-pages but none that mark a region of a string as super-scripted the way there are for bidi regions.

If you're trying to display mathematical text with super-scripts using a Graphics context, you should search for Latek or MathML libraries written in Java.

Answer (score 3):

You can use html tags in java (User Interface only):
Suppose you want to display 2<sup>10</sup>, write this code in your JLabel :

```
JLabel lab = JLabel("2<html><sup>10</sup></html>");
```

Answer (score 2):

A String does not store formatting information. To use superscript, you will have to fiddle with the Font of the displaying component. Checkout the [API on Font](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in java strings and some other cases also using Unicode Character super script...look at this [link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00b3/index.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example how to superscript the string "JavaTM" in Java.

in `as1.addAttribute method` '4' is the **beginIndex** Index of the first character and '6' is the **endIndex** Index of the character for superscript.

**Example:**

```
public class TextAttributesSuperscript extends JPanel {
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    AttributedString as1 = new AttributedString("JavaTM");
    as1.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT, TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT_SUPER, 4, 6);
    g2d.drawString(as1.getIterator(), 15, 60);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Java Superscript Example");
    frame.add(new TextAttributesSuperscript());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setSize(320, 190);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

**Output of this program:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using unicode characters as seen here:

```
   System.out.println("cm\u00b2");
   System.out.println("meter/second\u00b2");
   System.out.println("meter/second\u00b3");
```

This results in the below output:

```
cm²
meter/second²
meter/second³
```

More unicode characters can be found here - https://unicode-table.com/en/