# Output a number raised to a power as a string

Tags: java, android, numbers

I am new to Java and I'm not quite sure how to output an integer raised to a power as a string output. I know that

```
Math.pow(double, double)
```

will actually compute the value of raising a double to a power. But if I wanted to output "2^6" as an output (except with 6 as a superscript and not with the carat), how do I do that?

EDIT: This is for an Android app. I'm passing in the integer raised to the power as a string and I would like to know how to convert this to superscript in the UI for the phone.

Comment: Not sure if there is superscript 6, but if there is, write your own String conversion. EDIT: There is - U+00B2, U+00B3, U+00B9, U+2070, U+2074-U+2079.

Comment: Are we talking a console program here? A web application? A GUI? Please specify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're outputting the text to the GUI then you can use [HTML formatting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html) and the [`<sup>` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_sup.asp) to get a superscript. Otherwise, you'll have to use Unicode characters to get the other superscripts. Wikipedia has a nice article on superscripts and subscripts in Unicode:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts

Answer (score 12):

Unicode does have superscript versions of the digits 0 to 9: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts

This should print 2⁶:

```
 System.out.println("2⁶");

 System.out.println("2\u2076");
```

Comment: `System.out.println("2\u2076")` would print `2\u2076`. We really would need to do `System.out.println("2" + '\u2076')` using single quotes to show it's a `char`

Comment: @BrainFRZ? Really? Why wouldn't the escape sequence work inside of a String?

Answer (score 0):

This answer should only be used if using Eclipse (a java editor) what eclipse does is it only supports certain Unicode symbols.  1 2 and 3 can all be done and are supported by eclipse, anything else you have to play with the settings of eclipse which isnt too hard. There's this thing called Windows-1252 which is the default for a lot of stuff it seems, including being the default encoding for files in Eclipse. So, whenever you're printing to the console, that's what it's trying to interpret it as, and it doesn't support the full unicode charset since it's a 1 byte encoding. This isn't actually a problem with the Java, then, it's a problem with Eclipse, which means you need to edit your Eclipse to use UTF-8 instead. You can do this in multiple places; if you just want the unicode characters to be displayed when you're running this one file, you can right click the file, properties -> resource -> text file encoding and change from default to other: utf-8. If you want to do this to your whole workspace, you can go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Text file encoding. You could also do this project-wide or even just package-wide following pretty similar steps depending what you're going for.