# Get the text of textview and paste it on other one

Tags: java, android, html, textview

I have a TextView, and on it, is written H<sub>2</sub>O. Now onClick I want to copy the text of the first textview and paste it on a another one.

Answer (score 0):

inside your onClick method copy and paste this code:

```
String theText= textview1.getText().toString();//get the text from the textview
textview2.setText(theText);//set the text to the other textview
```

Comment: String can't save subscript

Comment: i found this answer for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058768/superscript-in-java-string