# Can we display superscript text in jdialog title?

Tags: java

I need to display part of text as superscript in jdialog title. Is it possible to display superscript in jdialog title? If yes how can we do it?  I tried this with `<html>Library Module<sup>New</sup></html>`. It is displaying as it is. That is its not showing as superscript text. Please provide an example. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [superscript in Java String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058768/superscript-in-java-string)

Comment: I tried that. But I am not getting. And I even tried this also.. <html>Library Module<sup>New</sup></html>. It is displaying as it is. That is its not showing as superscript text