# How to write the superscript text in java?

Tags: java

I want to display meter/second(2) in the output of acceleration as units. Which keyword should I use?

```
public class Distance {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int distance,init_velocity,time,acceleration;
    acceleration=10;
    init_velocity=20;
    time=20;
    distance=(init_velocity*time)+((acceleration*time*time)/2);
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Distance travelled by John ="+ distance+"  "+"meters" );
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------");
  }  
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058768/superscript-in-java-string

Answer (score 2):

Try:`System.out.println("meter/second\u00b2");`

Comment: Add more details to your solution, please

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the previous answer from @shachar - this can be achieved using unicode characters as seen here:

```
   System.out.println("cm\u00b2");
   System.out.println("meter/second\u00b2");
   System.out.println("meter/second\u00b3");
```

This results in the below output:

```
cm²
meter/second²
meter/second³
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class JavaBasics
{    public static void main(String args[])
    {   System.out.println("Enter the Side in metere");
        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        int s =obj.nextInt();
        int area = s*s;
        System.out.println("Your area of Square is = "+area+***"m\u00b2***");

    }
}
```

Comment: \u00b2 means Subscript 2 of previous number