# Representing two strings in superscript in java

Tags: java, html, unicode, subscript, superscript

I have two strings for example "2" and "3". How can I represent them in the form 2^3 in string in java?

I tried using "string 1" + "\u00b" + "string 2". But that didn't work. Can someone please help me with it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [superscript in Java String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058768/superscript-in-java-string)

Comment: It might help if you provided where you are trying to print (e.g some IDE console) and the OS.

Comment: You have misunderstood how Unicode escapes work.  `\u00b2` is *one character.*  It cannot be split up.  You can create a simple mapping, like `Map<String, String> superscripts = Map.of("2", "\u00b2", "3", "\u00b3");`.

Comment: Be specific about the environment you will be using to render the superscript characters (e.g. The console, Android, Swing, etc.), and your version of Java. And why do you have a tag of html for this question?

Answer (score 1):

Using Windows and Eclipse, this worked for me.

- Window->Preferences->General->Workspace

At the bottom see `Text file encoding`

- change to `ISO-8859-1` or `windows-1252`

```
System.out.println("km\u00B2");
System.out.println("2\u00B3");
```

prints

```
km²
2³
```

**Updated Info**

This appears to be a bug prior to Java 19 where it was fixed.  Check out [bug_id=8284778](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8284778).  Until users upgrade to Java 19, [skomisa's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75398769/representing-two-strings-in-superscript-in-java/75399383#comment133047217_75399383) should work.  For Eclipse (and perhaps other IDE's), one can use the `sun.stdout.encoding` property.  As noted in the above bug report it is **undocumented and unsupported**. To make it the default in `Eclipse`:

- go to `Window->Preferences->Installed JREs`
- click on the current JRE and select edit
- in the `Default VM arguments:` add `-Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8`
- apply and close.

Comment: Why only ISO-8859-1 and windows-1252?  UTF-8 is practically universal.

Comment: @VGR My eclipse was already set for UTF-8.  It didn't work in the console.  I tried both of these and they worked.  When I set it back to UTF-8 it no longer worked.  I have no explanation as to why.

Comment: @WJS I think there may be a conflict between the encoding used by `System.out()` and the encoding used by your Eclipse console, even though you were _"set for UTF-8"_. Try calling `System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF8"));` before calling `println()` without switching to `ISO-8859-1` or `windows-1252` and I think it may work. Alternatively just run your app from a terminal/cmd window instead of within Eclipse (without calling `setOut()`) and I think it may work. In general, IDE consoles are an unreliable environment when using `println()` for non ASCII characters.

Comment: Your suggestion worked!  When printing the default charset `System,out.charSet()` it printed `windows-1252` when `Text file encoding` was set to `UTF-8`.  After your suggestion, it printed `UTF-8`. So I presume they had to match one way or the other.  Since `UTF-8` is preferred, your way of achieving this is preferred (although a default would be nice).  You should post this as an answer.  My version of Eclipse is `Version: 2022-09 (4.25.0)`
and `Build id: 20220908-1902`

Comment: Your code (and nothing more) worked fine for me in Eclipse 2022-12 (4.26.0). But I'm running on Windows 10 with the checkbox _"Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support"_ checked in _Region Settings_ in _Control Panel_, so `System.out.charset()` printed "UTF-8" for me, as expected. I also tried in NetBeans, but even though `System.out.charset()` also printed "UTF-8", I had to call `setOut()` to render the superscripts properly. I have no idea why, but I've often found Java I/O to be tricky when run within an IDE on Windows.

Comment: Anyway, all that is not directly related to the OP's question about superscripts, which I think you have answered.

Comment: Good catch finding that bug. I was using JDK 19 in Eclipse, but JDK 18 in NetBeans. Once I upgraded NetBeans to JDK 19 the call to `setOut()` was not needed. Also, in JDK 19, **stdout.encoding** is the new and formally supported successor to the unsupported property **sun.stdout.encoding**. See the [JDK 19 Javadoc for `System.getProperties()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()). It's worth noting that its only supported value is _"UTF-8"_.