# Convert characters to underscore characters with utf-8

Tags: javascript, java, string, unicode, character

I'm surprised I could not find this but I notice Unicode contains underscore versions of the letters and I'd like something that could convert one to the other.

example:

https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1E0F

“ḏ” (U+1E0F)

and

“d” (U+0064)

Has anyone written a character converter to allow me to take a substring and convert some characters to their underscore versions?  I'm not 100% sure of the relationships.

Java or JavaScript or C# or other would be fine.

TIA

This is for a menu in JavaFX. I could do it with a graphic maybe but I would lose styles.

Comment: Basically how do I convert from ascii to the underscored variant.  That's what I'm interested in.

Comment: Not all letters from Basic Latin (A-Z) have a matching character with a line below. For example, `A` does not, while `B` does. See [*Latin Extended Additional*](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+1E00) block page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this. Use the diacritic `(\\u0332)` for underscoring.

```
String uscore = "\u0332";
for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
    String s = uscore + c;
    System.out.print(s + " ");        
    
}
```

prints

```
a̲ b̲ c̲ d̲ e̲ f̲ g̲ h̲ i̲ j̲ k̲ l̲ m̲ n̲ o̲ p̲ q̲ r̲ s̲ t̲ u̲ v̲ w̲ x̲ y̲ z̲
```

**Caveat:**  When printing with `Eclipse`, those that go below the base line don't show as underscored in the console. They do show up when I paste them into the answer.  It may be due to the fact that I have not upgraded to `JDK 19` as per the bug report on `System.out` support as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75399383/1552534)

Answer (score 2):

What would a screen reader read the underlined characters as?

JavaFX has [keyboard mnemonics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/MenuItem.html#mnemonicParsingProperty) built-in and enabled by default. All you have to do is put an underscore before the letter you want to use.

Also, there are [accelorators](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-add-accelerators-to-a-menu-item) if you want to show keyboard shortcuts beside menu items.

Comment: This answer clearly doesn't answer what OP is asking for. However, it correctly surmises that OP has fallen afoul of the X/Y rule: OP wants a certain thing 'X' (X = underscores in JavaFX menus), and has thought of a solution 'Y' (Y = use unicode chars that look like basic alphabet letters with underscores), but now has questions about Y. However, Y is a really bad solution to X. I'm not quite certain what SO policy is, but, this helps the asker and is likely highly relevant to anybody asking 'how do I convert from ascii to the underscored variant', so, this serves as the best answer.

Comment: @DaveS Yeah true but the user needs to press <alt> to enable it.  In my case my "menu" is just a series of styled buttons. I'm just wondering if there's a defined relationship with these characters like upper and lower can easily be converted with with addition or subtraction.

Comment: @DanHoward Your complaint boils down to: "Yeah but I hate how JavaFX does it / I hate how the OS itself even works, so for just my one app I want to completely reinvent it all, and, uh, screenreaders? Accessibility? I don't know what that means". You see how you should just do the thing the OS and JavaFX libraries intend for you to do to have accelerators for the menu, and not handroll your own solution here.

Comment: @rzwitserloot It's a question. Not a complaint.

Comment: I think you'll just have to use string replacement function calls. I.e. `str.replace("d", "\u1E0F");`. You could build a function that takes a normal letter, and replaces it via a map, but you'd probably have to build that map manually.